# What does the following ^.*$ regexp match?

Tags: java, regex, validation

Can someone explain what the following regexp matches?

```
^.*$
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like this is well-covered in http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.  What was wrong with the official documentation?

Answer (score 21):

*Either* the entire string *or* the entire line, depending on whether [multiline mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) is used.

Answer (score 15):

everything.

```
^ is the beginning of the string. 
. is any character. 
* means 0 or more of said characters. 
$ is the end of the string.
```

So this regex matches 0 or more characters that start and end a string (which is everything).

Comment: By default, most regex implementations will not match `\r` and `\n` for the DOT meta char. So, not "everything".

Comment: @Bart K. Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

It matches all empty and non-empty lines. It can be broken down into the following parts:

```
^ : match the beginning of the line
. : match any character except newline
* : match zero or many instances of the match
$ : match the ending of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

It will match anything.

`^` signifies the start of the line. `$` signifies the end of the line. So this means that the expression must match the entire string it is passed.

`.` will match any single character. `*` means that the thing before it can appear between 0 to any number of times. So this means that the string can have any number of characters, including 0.

Answer (score 1):

`^` = Start of string or line (depends on settings).

`.` = Any character.

`*` = Any number of the previous character.  In this case the `.`.

`$` = End of string or line (depends on settings).

Put them together and it can match either a whole string or one whole line depending on what the multiline settings are (see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it matches everything...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Ankur: disagree. It does *directly* answer the question, albeit with little explanation. It's also, strictly speaking, not entirely correct, but that too does not mean it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it matches everything including empty strings.  The .* means that it matches everything (the period) 0 or more times (the *).  The ^ and the $ are redundant if you have set the multline flag (not sure what it is in java).